How to recover wireless connection to Internet without reboot?
I use Lubuntu 22.04 on Lenovo B 50 10.
Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
The laptop has a crack on the case. From time to time the Wi-Fi connection turns off, especially if it is carelessly moved to another place. In this case, the nm-applet application loses the ability to select a Wi-Fi network for connection.
I try to input command:
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager

This restores the ability to select a Wi-Fi network for connection, but not always. however even if I connect to the router, Internet sites do not open, and the Google DNS server does not ping.
I have to reboot, but even after rebooting, the Wi-Fi connection can quickly disappear, and I have to reboot again.

P.S. I've used a command:
echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=0 ips=0 ant_sel=2" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf

The wifi connection seems to be stable for some time. rtl8723be chip is a problematic one as many Linux users complained about it.

You have a serious hardware problem that no software is going to fix. Time to take the machine for repair or replace.

The " crack on the case" suggests that somebody dropped the laptop. If the impact was hard enough to crack the case, it did other, internal damage as well, leading to an intermittent connection to your WiFi card. Repair, replace, or get a dongle.

Edit to post results for iwconfig after the problem occurs

@Jeremy31 I put fwlps=0 in modprobe as is written below and the wifi stopped turning off for now.

You can use modprobe command to activate/deactivate the wireless drivers:

modprobe runs or stops a module from running. Most wireless drivers
in Ubuntu are in a module form. The following commands remove or add a
module.
(i) When a recognized device loads, the kernel automatically loads the
correct module for the device. This command is only needed to manually
run a module

To start a module run this command:
sudo modprobe <module>

To stop and remove a module run this command:
sudo modprobe -r <module>


I do not see how this will work when the OP says he has a hardware damaged computer.

@talaat-etman Probably it should be "rtlwifi" or "rtl8723be" module. When I try to stop it with modprobe, I get a message that the module is in use. Even if I manage to revive Network Manager to see wifi networks around, for some reason I cannot connect to any of them. Only after reboot it connects. Weird

sudo modprobe -r rtl8723be and sudo modprobe  rtl8723be

see this WiFi fix for the Realtek rtl8723be Wireless card in Ubuntu: https://github.com/roopansh/rtl8723be_wifi

@talaat-etman The fix completely turned off wifi on reboot. I tried twice to reboot. I found another fix that saved me from dead wireless device. echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf

Note that with hardware damage, it's more than likely you have actual damage to the system and simply software solutions won't solve this.  Especially if the connection internally is damaged.  You really need to get your system repaired or replaced @user282981

@thomas-ward No disconnect in couple days once I put fwlps=0. I moved laptop from room to room, made it sleep and awake. The old cripple provides me Internet.
